# How to use treeview control with data grid view column in c# windows

Tags: c#

I have a data grid view which is bind by a SQLite data source. I have to manage parent child relation in grid view. Is it possible by using tree view control in data grid view?

Comment: No, that only works well when you make the parent selectable in the TreeView and show the child data in the grid.